# Can the differential operator $1-\lambda e^{aD}$ be written in matrix form?

Tags: operator-theory, physics

Let $f(q)$ be a function over the real numbers us and consider the shift operator of Quantum mechanics: $\operatorname{Sh}_a$ which upon acting on $f(q)$, gives us its shifted value: $\operatorname{Sh}_a(f)(q) =  f(q + a)$, with $a>0$ a given positive number.

It is known that $\operatorname{Sh}(f)$ can be written in the operator form:
$\operatorname{Sh}_a(f)(q) = e^{a D}(f)$, where  $D = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}q}$ is the derivative operator with respect to the variable $q$.
Let us further consider another   given function of $q$: $\lambda_2(q)$.

My question is: Is it possible to write the  new operator $(1 - \lambda_2(q)e^{a D})$ in matrix form?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What would be the basis of the matrix representation?

Comment: Esteemed rob john, the natural basis for the problem I want to solve is formed by decaying exponentials of the type: e^{- \nu q}, with \nu a positive odd integer.